# how to block off permission to all folders but one in C Drive

Tags: security, directory

I have just set up a new user for ftp connection first time. I am trying to block off all permissions on all c drive folders but their their user folder. Currently they can see files in the windows folder which I tried changing using the properties and security deny permission for user, but it didnt allow me to do it.

Whats the best way to set this up? And block all visual access to folders but their own user folder.

Any questions, let me know and I'll clarify as best as I can.

Comment: You might find a better reception on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com). StackOverflow is more for programming-specific questions, while ServerFault is dedicated to more general administrative issues

Answer (score 0):

Can use bitvise to restrict users to a root directory without touching any permissions on the directory itself